# Encoding Issue in Talend Open Studio

Tags: csv, encoding, ascii, talend, utf

I am working on a Talend Project, Where we are Transforming data from 1000's of XML files to CSV and we are creating CSV file encoding as UTF-8 from Talend itself.

But the issue is that some of the Files are created as UTF-8 and some of them created as ASCII , I am not sure why this is happening The files should always be created as UTF.

Comment: What is telling you that your file is ASCII or UTF8

Comment: I am using commad `file FileName` on Linux system.

Comment: ASCII is a valid subset of UTF8. If your file doesn't contain anything other than ASCII characters then it will be seen as ASCII even if the file is outputted as UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Advanced tab of the tFileOutputDelimited (or other kind of tFileOutxxx) you are using and select UTF-8 encoding.

Here is an image of the advanced tab where to perform the selection
[image]

I am quite sure the unix file util makes assumptions based on content of the file being in some range and or having specific start (magic numbers). In your case if you generate a perfectly valid UTF-8 file, but you just use only the ASCII subset the file util will probably flag it as ASCII. In that event you are fine, as you have a valid UTF-8 file. :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The OP's real problem is, as mentioned in the comments, that UTF8 is a superset of ASCII. If you don't have any non ASCII characters in a file that is encoded in UTF8 it will be seen as ASCII (unless the file type specially allows for encoding declarations).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR From the OP question I understand he needs to be sure his file is encoded in UTF8. I explained how he can do that in Talend. I think this solves his need.

I also understand that in some cases (UTF8 file using only ASCII characters) the two encodings cannot be distinguished from the file content, but OP's problem is not how to tell if it's UTF8 or not; his problem is to be sure to generate UTF8 encoded files.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, UTF8 is a superset of ASCII. This means that the code point for any ASCII characters will be the same in UTF8 as ASCII.

Any program identifying a file containing only ASCII characters will then simply assume it is ASCII encoded. It is only when you include characters outside of the ASCII character set that the file may be recognised by whatever heuristic the reading program uses.

The only exception to this is for file types that specifically state their encoding. This includes things like (X)HTML and XML which typically start with an encoding declaration.

Answer (score 0):

To force talend to get a file as you wish, you can add an additional column to your file (for example in a tMap) and set an UTF-8 character in this column. The generated file will be in UTF8 as the other repliers mentioned.