# Does Talend Support UTF-8 Encoding for Excel Headers?

Tags: excel, encoding, utf-8, talend, talend-mdm

I am new to Talend, and I have this Excel sheet, which has UTF-8 Letters in the headers, that i want to profile using Talend DQ, Now, I was able to import the list and in the preview everything is shown correctly; however, When I Click next, all the UTF-8 encoded letters are change into "Column0, Column1, ....

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's say something, if they cannot support UTF-8 and they announce themselves as: "integration software provider to data-driven enterprises. Our customers connect anywhere, at any speed. From ground to cloud and batch to streaming, data or application integration" then they failed in their business. So I would go for yes, they have to, but I do not have the experience on this to tell. You can always just try it, is open source.

Comment: I also found this for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343580/encoding-issue-in-talend-open-studio maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In advanced option of your Input Excel File component there is a field that allow to select the encoding you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding in Advanced settings if for content, header is based on field names which must respect Java namming rules convention (no accent, no special character and so on).
In short, if you need header with composed UTF-8 characters, don't use the standard "Include header" option, do it by yourself.